# InputStreamReader throws NullPointerException when launching via cmd

Tags: java, cmd, nullpointerexception, inputstream, bufferedreader

I wrote some code to open and read the content of a csv file:

```
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)));
 String line;

 try {
     line = bufferedReader.readLine();

     while (line != null) {
         line = bufferedReader.readLine();
     }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     // close buffered reader
 }
```

The code is working fine in unit tests, no exception is raised. However once I try to launch the program via cmd it throws a NPE coming from InputStreamReader:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exercise.FileLoader.loader(FileLoader.java:28)
    at exercise.Application.main(Application.java:22)
```

The program takes actually the file name as parameter:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("Too many input arguments.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    String fileName = args[0];
    //here runs the method who reads the csv file above
 }
```

Could you tell me what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following reads **not a File** on the *file system*, but a **resource** on the *class path* (principly read-only).

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)));
```

Also the encoding is that of current platform, which might differ on another PC.
And I see no `close()` which probably got deleted on preparing the question.

For the file system:

```
Path path = Paths.get(filename);
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader =
             Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
     line = ...
     ...
} // Automatic close.
```

There has to be taken some care when the path is not absolute. Then it depends where the "working directory" points to, where the application is started.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the program being unable to find the file once you launch the program via cmd.
Have you tried putting the program in the same folder of the file? You could also ask for a user's input in the main so that you can provide the correct folder.

Comment: In case you go for the user's input, try giving the absolute path of the file(C:\path\etc..)

Comment: I tried both (putting the file under the same folder as the exe then giving simply the csv file name as param and giving the full path). And yes in the main I ask the user to provide the file name that how it bugged. Will edit the question description right now.